# Android L native build not working

Tags: android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to build native library of Android L with preview SDK. I am getting following error:

```
....ndk/build/gmsl/__gmsl:512: *** non-numeric second argument to `wordlist' function: 'L'.  Stop.

**** Build Finished ****
```

Could somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, Someone has already down-voted the question.

Anyway, it looks like there will be a developer preview NDK available soon for Android L

Thanks